# GnuRadio python interpolation blocks

Tags: python, gnuradio

I've been working through [Gnuradio tutorials](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_Python) in order to understand how blocks are made.

I am trying to make an interpolation block (1 input : 2 outputs) that returns the input values multiplied by a constant in both output streams. I've implemented this as a class, multiply_out_fff() that inherits from an interp_block

```
import numpy
from gnuradio import gr

class multiply_out_fff(gr.interp_block):
    """ 
    docstring for block multiply_out_fff
    """
    def __init__(self, multiple):
        gr.interp_block.__init__(self,
            name="multiply_out_fff",
            in_sig=[numpy.float32],
            out_sig=[numpy.float32], interp = 2)
        self.multiple = multiple


    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        in0 = input_items[0]
        out = output_items[0]

        print("the data coming in: ", in0)
        print("in shape ",in0.shape)

        for i in range(0,len(out)/2):
          out[i] = in0[i] * self.multiple
        for i in range(len(out)/2,len(out)):
          out[i] = in0[i-len(out)] * self.multiple

        print("the data going out: ", out)
        print("out shape ", out.shape)

        return len(output_items[0])
```

I've written a test for this block, and have managed to get it to pass, but not in the way I originally thought would work

```
from gnuradio import gr, gr_unittest
from gnuradio import blocks
from multiply_out_fff import multiply_out_fff

class qa_multiply_out_fff (gr_unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp (self):
        self.tb = gr.top_block ()

    def tearDown (self):
        self.tb = None

    def test_001_t (self):
        # set up fg
        self.data = (0,1,-2,5.5)
        self.expected_result = (0,2,-4,11,0,2,-4,11)

        print("---------testing----------")
        print("test data: ", self.data)

        #make blocks
        self.src = blocks.vector_source_f(self.data)
        self.mult = multiply_out_fff(2)
        self.snk1 = blocks.vector_sink_f()
        self.snk2 = blocks.vector_sink_f()

        #make connections
        self.tb.connect((self.src,0),(self.mult,0))
        self.tb.connect((self.mult,0),(self.snk1,0))
        #self.tb.connect((self.mult,1),(self.snk2,0))
        self.tb.run ()

        self.result_data1 = self.snk1.data()
        #self.result_data2 = self.snk2.data()

        print("The output data: ", self.result_data1)
        print("--------test complete-------------\n")

        # check data
        self.assertFloatTuplesAlmostEqual(self.expected_result, self.result_data1)
        #self.assertFloatTuplesAlmostEqual(self.expected_result, self.result_data2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gr_unittest.run(qa_multiply_out_fff, "qa_multiply_out_fff.xml")
```

running the test script gives:

```
 ~/gnuradio/gr-tutorial/python$ python qa_multiply_out_fff.py 
---------testing----------
('test data: ', (0, 1, -2, 5.5))
('the data coming in: ', array([ 0. ,  1. , -2. ,  5.5], dtype=float32))
('in shape ', (4,))
('the data going out: ', array([  0.,   2.,  -4.,  11.,   0.,   2.,  -4.,  11.], dtype=float32))
('out shape ', (8,))
('The output data: ', (0.0, 2.0, -4.0, 11.0, 0.0, 2.0, -4.0, 11.0))
--------test complete-------------

.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
```

The concept I'm struggling to understand is how my block returns data. Right now, it returns both interpolation output streams in a single array with twice the length of the input. I thought it should have two independent output arrays, and allow me to have a separate sink connected to each output, like this (commented out in the test):

```
    self.tb.connect((self.mult,0),(self.snk1,0))
    self.tb.connect((self.mult,1),(self.snk2,0))
```

Instead, all my data flows into snk1. If I uncomment the second connection, I receive an error informing me that the self.mult block can't have more output connections.

```
ValueError: port number 1 exceeds max of 0
```

How can I make an interpolation block I can make multiple output connections with?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I misunderstood the 'interp' parameter, which specifies the ratio between input vector length and output vector length. The proper way to make multiple outputs for this block is to **modify the 'out_sig' parameter to be a list of output types**, as shown below in the modified multiply_out_fff class.

```
import numpy
from gnuradio import gr

class multiply_out_fff(gr.interp_block):
    """ 
    docstring for block multiply_out_fff
    """
    def __init__(self, multiple):
        gr.interp_block.__init__(self,
            name="multiply_out_fff",
            in_sig=[numpy.float32],
            out_sig=[numpy.float32,numpy.float32], interp = 1)
        self.multiple = multiple


    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        in0 = input_items[0]
        out1 = output_items[0]
        out2 = output_items[1]    
#        print("the data coming in: ", in0)
#        print("in shape ",in0.shape)

        for i in range(len(in0)):
          out1[i] = in0[i] * self.multiple

        for i in range(len(in0)):
          out2[i] = in0[i] * self.multiple * 2 

#        print("the data going out: ", out)
#        print("out shape ", out.shape)

        return len(output_items[0])
```

[Gnuradio Reference](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki/Guided_Tutorial_GNU_Radio_in_Python)

Gnuradio - "If we wanted vectors, we could define those as in_sig=[(numpy.float32,4),numpy.float32]. This means there are two input ports, one for vectors of 4 floats and the other for scalars."